# SQL Inserting rows as columns

Tags: sql, select, view, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I have data like this:

```
ID (UID), EID (ID of record), Name (Name of meta-field), Value (value of meta-field)

 - 1,1,Name,A 
 - 2,1,Note,B  
 - 3,1,Additional,C
 - 4,2,Name,Z
 - 5,2,Note,Z  
 - 6,2,Additional,Z
 - 7,3,Name,RICE
 - 8,3,Note,DICE 
 - 9,3,Additional,MICE
```

I need a select (view) that looks like this:

```
EID, Name, Note, Additional

 - 1,A,B,C 
 - 2,Z,Z,Z  
 - 3,Rice,Dice,Mice
```

I tried several selects but cant seem to get it, or find a suitable answer that helps, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Will it always be just three columns with specific names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/902e3/1))

```
SELECT t.EID, tname.Value Name, tnote.Value Note, tadd.Value Additional
  FROM Table1 t
  INNER JOIN Table1 tname ON tname.Name = "Name" AND tname.EID = t.EID
  INNER JOIN Table1 tnote ON tnote.Name = "Note" AND tnote.EID = t.EID
  INNER JOIN Table1 tadd  ON tadd.Name  = "Additional" AND tadd.EID = t.EID
GROUP BY t.EID
```

Since answering this I've acquired more knowledge of SQL variants other than MySQL. This would be a (more graceful) solution for MS SQL-Server:

```
select * from (
  select EID, Name as Col, Value from Table1
) p
pivot (
  min(Value)
  for Col in (Name, Note, Additional)
) pvt
```

(Note that aliasing `Name` to `Col` is necessary because it would conflict with the `Name` column of the pivoted result)